# Adjusting the response variable to incorporate scaling effects

Tags: random-forest, count-data, dependent-variable

I am using a random forest regression to model a count of species from a number of different survey areas. Each survey area has a different size.

My question is how to model the response variable, to account for these scaling effects? Should I scale the Count prior to fitting the model?

```
Count <- Count / Survey_area_km2
model < fit(Count ~ pred1 + pred2 + ...)
```

And then when predicting over a set of survey areas, adjust the response variable prediction by the size of the survey areas I am trying to predict. This will give a count that is in proportion to each survey area?

```
Count_predictions <- predict(model, prediction_areas)
Rescaled_Counts <- Count_predictions * prediction_areas
```

Comment: The usual model in your situation is a Poisson rate regression (search this site!), that is, log link function and log area as offset.  See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50786/predicting-count-data-with-random-forest

Comment: ... and    [this stored google search](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk03I0EFwUALRm_NiGOzFDDKMW4qK1w%3A1595096460416&ei=jD0TX9KBGfqj5OUPtLqk-AM&q=poisson+regression+with+random+forrest&oq=poisson+regression+with+random+forrest&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIHCCMQsAIQJzIGCAAQFhAeUABYAGD7hAFoAHAAeACAAWGIAWGSAQExmAEAqgEHZ3dzLXdpeg&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjS956vtdfqAhX6EbkGHTQdCT8Q4dUDCAs&uact=5)

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I hadn't realised there was a function `gbm.fit` that allows specification for an offset - it doesn't seem feasible if just using `gbm`. So when I use this the model fit is calculated on the log link scale? Therefore I should define it as `model <- gbm.fit(x=predictors, y=response, offset=log(Area))` ?

Comment: You can find more information [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=R+gbm+with+poisson+regression+and+log+link+site:stats.stackexchange.com&safe=off&sxsrf=ALeKk03Nk-i0zCJ7zSVluj_PqiVY8PEvcg:1595177168373&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiL3uWD4tnqAhXbDrkGHblVDJIQrQIoBHoECAYQBQ&biw=1279&bih=615).